# Combine and minify all bower libraries into one file webpack

Tags: javascript, css, gulp, bower, webpack

I use bower to require my fronted css/js dependencies, I referenced all of them from my index.html view which also include my react app bundle in this html.

For the bundle.js of my react app everything is OK and webpack does the job well.

My question is how can I automate the process of combining all the style import from bower_component directory using webpack (css + js) ?

Does a tool can go throw the index.html file and then when see the import (which in my case is something like this :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/plugins/select2/dist/css/select2.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/plugins/summernote/dist/summernote.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/plugins/ion.rangeslider/css/ion.rangeSlider.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/plugins/ion.rangeslider/css/ion.rangeSlider.skinFlat.css">
<script src="/public/plugins/summernote/dist/summernote.min.js"></script>
```

replace the content of the file using the URL of the file, moreover even if the URL is relative and defined static in expressJS.

- Gulp can be the tool but it would be great if one tool can do all the job. 
  Gulp inject seems interesting https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-inject but no options for relative URL and to take only the file required in the index.html file.

I cannot use gulp and say all the js/css in the bower component because they are not all used and I don't want to more them to be able to update the component easily.